# Cannot navigate to laravel project via localhost using Apache

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4, virtualhost

I installed a laravel project to `/home/user/development`. The project is called rpm (`/home/user/development/rpm`). I also have another project that I have been using at `/home/public_html`. It's called mgmt (`/home/user/public_html/mgmt`). I can navigate just fine to mgmt via *localhost/mgmt*. It's conf file in `sites-available` is

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/

<Directory /home/user/public_html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/rpm-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/rpm-access.log combined

 </VirtualHost>
```

Now my laravel project (rpm) does not work. Navigating to *localhost/rpm* gives a 404.
It's conf file looks like this

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /home/user/development/rpm/public/
Alias /rpm /home/user/development/rpm/public

<Directory /home/user/development/rpm/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/rpm-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/rpm-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

What could be the problem here? Both of those config files have symlinks in the `sites-enabled` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the first conf to this. Discard the second conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/

Alias /rpm /home/user/development/rpm/public

<Directory /home/user/public_html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/development/rpm/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/rpm-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/rpm-access.log combined

 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: that made everything inside localhost including localhost a 403 forbidden access.

Comment: Do you have `mod_alias` enabled? What is the output of `sudo apache2ctl -M | sort`?

Comment: dude I just gave up. I thank you tons for helping me. I just installed nginx and im going to try and use that